# Can one practice generative linguistics without the UG baggage?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, generative-grammar

I'm very skeptical about Chomsky's UG axioms.
Of course he revised his concept continually, or so it seems.
In the end, I don't see any evidence yet for a 'language gene' as Pinker ridiculously posited roughly 3 decades ago.
So I believe one can very much so treat language as a broader cognitive ability rather than something distinct from it - "language organ", they say.

I'm still a bachelor student in linguistics and my modus operandi is: Even if I don't like the above-mentioned axioms, one can still 'do' generative linguistics, namely the overall generative treatment of grammar seems very reasonable to me.

But on the other hand, I would like to find out more precisely where to not let down my guard. Or to put it differently:
How can I (from my more 'bayesian' perspective) detect the deficiencies within the generative framework? How can I clear out the malfunctions derived from those axioms?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without a more precise definition of "generativism" and "UG", which is unfortunately extremely hard to come by! Both of those terms are used for a lot of different things and treated as if their meaning is obvious.

Comment: Your 'ridiculous' is rather strong there and will prevent many people from interacting with you here, even if they also disagree with many of Chomsky or Pinker's ideas.

Comment: Some time after Pinker postulated a language gene, there is one language gene identified by human genetiticists: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/66260/36828

Comment: I find my wording very much on point and I repell the social pressure you're trying to apply here.
From what I recall, the interpretation of what FOXP2 actually does is contested.
Of course there is a genetic component to everything.
I need muscular control in order to speak etc. This is not what we are looking for.
Further, Pinker formulated the idea of  'A' language gene,
rather than having a polygenic conception
(I suppose for reasons of PR)

Comment: You may want to read this book first https://academic.oup.com/edited-volume/27996 esp. the introduction by Ian Roberts, to understand the terminology better https://academic.oup.com/edited-volume/27996/chapter-abstract/211709594?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: Yes, of course it is. The "UG baggage" is not at all necessary to describe syntactic phenomena. Read McCawley 1998 for real generative syntax with the epicycles left out.

Answer (score 3):

You can do without "the" UG baggage, but you cannot do without UG baggage. The difference is that "the UG baggage" is a time-specific set of claims – maybe X-bar theory, maybe the claim that all branching is binary, maybe A-over-A. But *some* UG baggage is the essential difference between generative grammar and generic grammar. The current trend (for syntax – things are different in other areas of grammar not led by Chomsky and his close followers)
starts out with the proper principle that maybe we should throw out a lot from the theory of grammar and simply say "That's learned" and "that's because of functional factors". However, they still end up with a bunch of rather arbitrary stipulative principles (like "checking").

We know that "checking" is not an essential mechanism of GG, because it didn't exist in GG for most of the life of GG. There are zillions of competing definitions of GG, but the one that I think most people accept is that it is the formal theory of "the language faculty". That presupposes that there is such a thing as "the language faculty", so if you think that language is just another kind of trained Pavlovian behavior, you're not doing generative grammar. Once (if) you accept that there is such a thing as "the language faculty", then what remains is answering the question "what is the nature of the language faculty". But there does exist a trend to the effect that there is nothing special about language; and those people are still doing linguistics, just non-generative linguistics.

Genetics is a distracting side-show. Sure, if humans have a faculty of reason, then it must have a genetic basis, but we know nothing about that basis.